# Swift dictionary bug?

Tags: dictionary, swift

So I started a project in Swift, and I've come to this problem:

this code works:

```
var dictionary = ["a":"valueOfA","b":"valueOfB","c":"valueOfC"]
println(dictionary)
dictionary["c"] = "newValOfC"
println(dictionary)
```

and this doesn't:

```
var dictionary = [:]
dictionary = ["a":"valueOfA","b":"valueOfB","c":"valueOfC"]
println(dictionary)
dictionary["c"] = "newValOfC"
println(dictionary)
```

Gives an error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:35:17: error: cannot assign to the result of this expression
dictionary["c"] = "newValC"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

Notice that this is not a constant value

So why doesn't the line

```
dictionary = ["a":"valueOfA","b":"valueOfB","c":"valueOfC"]
```

give an error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the context does not provide enough information to infer the type, you'll need to explicitly name it as a dictionary, otherwise swift assumes it is an `NSDictionary` (I'm not clear on why though. I assume for better obj-c compatibility):

The following code all works:

```
// Playground
import UIKit

var str:NSString = "Hello, playground"

var d0 = [:]
var d1: Dictionary = [:]

d0.setValue(UIWebView(), forKey: "asdf")

d1["asdf"] = 1
d1["qwer"] = "qwer"
```

Comment: I agree. `dictionary = [:]` creates `NSDictionary` but I don't know why

Comment: So basically it is not to initialize a `Dictionary` it is just to make it empty.

Comment: @GokhanArik   [:] cannot deduct out the key-value type of this dictionary literal. So by default it's NSDictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found it, the problem is that by initializing an empty dictionary, the type inference gets a little crazy.

You'll need this code:

```
var dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
```

instead of

```
var dictionary = [:]
```

but that still does not explain why the line

```
dictionary = ["a":"valueOfA","b":"valueOfB","c":"valueOfC"]
```

does not give an error

Comment: Just guessing: it may be that assigning a Dictionary to an NSDictionary is permitted. I have no access to the compiler. You may want to check the dynamic type after the assignment and/or declare another `var anotherDictionary = [ .... ]` with the Dictionary value and see if you can assign `dictionary = anotherDictionary` or not (and again check the dynamic type after the assignment).

Answer (score 3):

And referring to Swift Language Guide, the

```
dictionary = [:]
```

syntax is correct "if the context already provides type information".

Answer (score 2):

The big difference is that

```
var dictionary = [:]
```

doesn't give any chance the compiler to infer the right type, whereas

```
var dictionary = ["a":"valueOfA","b":"valueOfB","c":"valueOfC"]
```

does.

Actually it looks like the first line produces a `__NSDictionaryI` instance, whereas the second one produces a `Dictionary<String,String` as expected.

From *The Swift Programming Language* book

> If the context already provides type information, create an empty dictionary with an empty dictionary literal, which is written as [:] (a colon inside a pair of square brackets):

which means the first line is ambiguous.

Comment: and why is the second line not giving an error then?

Comment: that must be some quirk of the type inferencer, but everything comes down from the first line being ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The `[:]` syntax only works if the current context has enough information to be able to infer what the types are. Here are a few ways where the context is known...

As has been mentioned already, the code below works because it can be inferred that the keys and values are strings:

```
var dictionary = [ "a" : "valueOfA" , "b" : "valueOfB" , "c" : "valueOfC" ]
```

A dictionary passed into a function has a known context:

```
func dictionaryFunc(var dictionary : Dictionary<String, String>) {
    // Do stuff with the dictionary
}
```

In both cases, the key/value types for the dictionary are now known, so you could do this to create a new dictionary with the same variable name...

```
dictionary = [:]
```

In the first case, if you used the `[:]` syntax after the declaration you would be erasing the contents of the original dictionary. In the second case, dictionaries get copied when they get passed into functions, so using `[:]` would only be erasing the copy.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2.0 I'm using this:

```
var dictionary = [String:String]()
dictionary["key1"] = "value1"
```